# Discord Bot Python missing positional argument token

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, token

I'm a beginner python programmer trying to get my bot online, but I can't solve one error I keep getting. In tutorials, people usually run something like

```
client.run('TOKEN')
```

in the end, whereas TOKEN is the discord bot token. Pycharm doesn't recognize the token and gives the following error:

> TypeError: Client.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'

I tried typing

```
client.run(token='TOKEN')
```

but I'm afraid this is not the solution because then Pycharm tells me that the positional argument 'self' is missing.
I'm very new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the full code:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("print Befehl test")

client = MyClient
client.run(token='TOKEN')
```

Comment: I assume you have substituted the string `'TOKEN'` with the actual token, right?

Comment: The first one is correct. Can you post some more of your code so we can diagnose the real issue?

Comment: @yagod I did indeed

Comment: @MichaelM. I just edited the post, thank you for your feedback so far. :) I'm confused about where the issue is here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

client should be MyClient(), you have to actually instantiate it. Just add the parentheses.

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("print Befehl test")

client = MyClient()
client.run(token='TOKEN')
```

instead of just MyClient.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not instantiating `MyClass`. `client` is just a reference to the class `MyClass` itself. So, when you do `client.run()`, it is trying to run the function as a static method.

To fix this, just add parentheses after `MyClient`. Try this instead:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("print Befehl test")

client = MyClient()
client.run(token='TOKEN')
```

Comment: Yup, the critical distinction between the class itself and an instance of the class!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to add intents and after reseting my token, it finally worked. I'll post the code that solved the problem in a separate answer.

Comment: @SakurairoFuyu Out of curiosity, why did you choose to accept the other answer instead of this one?

Comment: @MichaelM. Initially I wanted to mark both as correct but I couldn't so I just stuck with the last answer I marked as correct, your answers have both helped me similarily though. :)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```py
import discord
    
    class MyClient(discord.Client):
        async def on_ready(self):
            print("print Befehl test")
    
    client = MyClient(intents=discord.Intents.all())
    client.run(token='TOKEN')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).